# Use extended object for constructor?

Tags: typescript

This is more of a general best practice question, but consider the following TypeScript code:

[Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20MyClass%7B%0A%09defaults=%7B%0A%09%09foo%3a%22foo%22,%0A%09%09bar%3a%20%22bar%22%0A%09%7D%0A%09options%3aany;%0A%09constructor%28%20options?%3aany%29%7B%0A%09%09this.options%20=%20%24.extend%28this.defaults,%20options%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20var%20%24;%0A%0Aclass%20Other%7B%0A%09constructor%28%29%7B%0A%09%09var%20myClass%3aMyClass=new%20MyClass%28%7Bfoo%3a%22foomanchu%22%7D%29;%0A%09%09console.log%28myClass.options.foo%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

```
class MyClass{
    defaults={
        foo:"foo",
        bar: "bar"
    }
    options:any;
    constructor( options?:any){
        this.options = $.extend(this.defaults, options);
    }
}

declare var $;

class Other{
    constructor(){
        var myClass:MyClass=new MyClass({foo:"foomanchu"});
        console.log(myClass.options.foo);
    }
}
```

The idea here is that MyClass should not have an endless constructor if possible, such as:

```
 myClass("foo", "bar", "some", "other", "stuff");
```

This is bad because if MyClass changes, every class that uses it has to update its constructor call.

But as another developer pointed out, if I have all of these things as constructor elements, I get nice code hinting. For instance, in IntelliJ, as soon as I type the parentheses, I get a list of every param that's expected. On the other hand, if I leave them as a "monadic" object, then the code in Other is far more readable. I know what the constructor variables are because I see them named. So for another developer reading my code, option 1 is better. For a person writing the code, option 2 is better since I get code hinting.

So question 1 is: which is better practice?

Question 2 is: is there a way I've overlooked to use option 1 and still get code hinting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public options: { foo?: string; bar?: string; } = {}) {
        this.options = $.extend({
            foo: "foo",
            bar: "bar"
        }, options);
    }
}

declare var $;

class Other {
    constructor() {
        var myClass: MyClass = new MyClass({ foo: "foomanchu" });
        console.log(myClass.options.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this comes closest to solving the problem. It still has the named object literal variables in the calling class, but enables additional options to be added later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a potential way.

```
class another{
    constructor(public foo = "foo", public bar = "bar"){
    }
}
var an:another = new another("foomanchu");
```

Comment: The argument against that is what if MyClass grows to need 5 or even 10 options? By using an object literal, the signature never changes, right?

Comment: You can keep adding new parameters in the constructor and if you have default value, you'll not need to change existing calls to the constructor.

Comment: Right, but would a person reading the code understand what new another("myValue") means? Isn't it better to make your code readable for maintenance purposes?

Comment: You do get intellisense when creating a new another()

Comment: Correct, but reading the calling class is harder. It's easier to understand what new PhotoBox({imagePath:"myimage.jpg", maxWidth: 500}); does vs. new PhotoBox("myimage.jpg", 500);

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not bad in my opinion - Similar to what you would do when building a JQuert widget.

Anyway, typescript has a "params"(if your familiar with C# you should know what I mean) feature where you can pass as many items you want.
I'm not sure it's the best thing to do, but it looks like this is what you wanted.

Here's a short example of params:

```
class Test {
    Method1(value: string) { // only for single string value
        alert("" + value);
    }
    Method2( ...params: number[]) { // Params but number type
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            alert("" + params[i]);
        }
    }
    Method3( ...params: any[]) { // params with any type
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            alert("" + params[i]);
        }
    }
}
window.onload = () =>{
    var data = new Test();
    data.Method1("Mcn Solution");
    data.Method2(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    data.Method3(1,"Mcn",3.3,'c');
}
```

Read some more [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/use-of-params-in-typescript/).

Comment: I think is really from where my question arises. In your example, a person reading the onload function wouldn't know what 1,2,3,4 5,6 meant. They'd have to dive into the Test class, which would probably be in a separate file, to figure out what each variable did. If we use the object literal and we name our variables well, then everything is clear to a new developer reading the code. That's the internal debate we're trying to resolve.